# Project Euler #8: C++ incorrect answer (gives correct for a small cooked up input)

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code for [problem #8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) on project euler (on C++). Note that `p8_data.txt` contains the digits that I copied from the problem statement. I double checked that it was indeed taking the correct digit every time I was reading from the file (although not for all the 1000 digits).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; 

int get_max_product(vector<long long> digits_of_num){

    // vector<int> product_digits(digits_of_num.size()-12);
    long long max = 1;
    int num_digits = 13; 
    cout << digits_of_num.size() << endl;
    for (int i=0; i <= digits_of_num.size()-num_digits; i++) {
        long long prod = 1; 
        for (int j=i; j < i+num_digits; j++){
            prod *= digits_of_num[j];
        // cout << j << endl;
        }
        if (prod > max){
            max = prod;
        }
    }
    return max; 
}

int main() {
// you don't really need the number, just the digits; 
// it treats the number in the file as characters
     ifstream inpFile;
     int num_digits = 1000;
     vector<long long> digits(num_digits); 
     char x;  
     inpFile.open("p8_data.txt");

     if (!inpFile){
         cerr << "Unable to open the requested file" << endl;
     }
     int sum = 0;
     while (inpFile >> x){
        digits[sum] = (long long)x - 48;
        cout << digits[sum] << " ";
        sum++;
     }
     inpFile.close();
     cout << "\nThe program ended happily with ending index = " << sum << endl; 
     long long max_product;
     max_product = get_max_product(digits);
     cout << max_product << endl;
     return 1;

}
```

but, for some reason, it gives an incorrect output: `2039787520`.

I have tried and tested several variations while extracting the digits (namely `(long long)x - 48)` and `(long) x - '0'` and several others. I have also tried to output `j` when taking the product of 13 consecutive digits, but that too is as expected (`987` to `999` for the last iteration of the for loop).

I got the answer by putting together a `python3` code but the idea is to practice `C++`.

Python:

```
import numpy as np 
import os 
from copy import deepcopy
import operator

def extract_digits(num):
    digits = []
    num = int(num)
    while (num/10 > 0):
        digits.append(deepcopy(num) % 10)
        num //= 10
    digits.reverse()
    return digits

def get_max_product(arr):
    max_prod = []
    # print(arr.size-13+)
    for i in range(len(arr) - 13):
        max_prod.append(np.prod(arr[i:i+13]))
    return max(max_prod)

with open('p8_data.txt') as rfil:
    lines = rfil.readlines()

nums = []
for line  in lines:
    nums.append(line.rstrip())

digits = []
for n in nums:
    digits.extend(extract_digits(n))

# digits = np.array(digits)
print(get_max_product(digits))
```

This gives `23514624000` which is the correct answer!

Could anyone point to what could be potentially going wrong with the `C++` code? I know this is a basic question, but any help would be appreciated.

Tried changin `long long` to `long` and so forth, but I am getting the same result.

I tried cooking up another string of numbers (a much shorter one though) out of curiosity, namely

`135689898
12999`

and ran the above `C++` code for this string with maximum product of `3` consecutive digits and the output was indeed `729`. I checked several other shorter strings too but the results were all correct. Only for the problem statement it yields an incorrect answer.

Comment: This seems like the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your program statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: And please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If in `x - 48` you really mean `x - '0'` then say so. Also think about what happens if there are more (or less) digits in the input file than the size of the vector. Perhaps you should only [*reserve*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) memory and push back elements, instead of setting a fixed size (that might be wrong).

Comment: Also naming variables max and the likes while at the same time using namespace std is dangerous at best

Comment: And signed integer arithmetic overflow is *undefined behavior*. If a multiplication leads to `prod` overflowing you will get very weird results.

Comment: Alright, will do! I don't clearly see how `prod` could overflow, but will step it through a debugger. I was alluding to more of a *logic* error, if present and left unspotted by me, in the code above.

Comment: @nada changed `max` to a more meaningful `max_product` but the result doesn't change. Thanks for pointing it out though!!

Comment: If there is an overflow problem, you should change the return type of get_max_product to long long, it's still an int.

Also, you don't need to change to long long the values of the vector of digits, they are only 0-9 digits.

Comment: @BhaveshShrimali It's recommended to not `using namespace std;` at all but instead write `using std::cout` and so on... This is a similar issue as writing `from some_package import *` in Python btw

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the function prototype:

```
int get_max_product(vector<long long> digits_of_num)
```

You are returning an `int` instead of an `long long`. Change it to

```
long long get_max_product(vector<long long> digits_of_num)
```

or better (C++14 or later)

```
auto get_max_product(vector<long long> digits_of_num)
```

Comment: Also please be aware (OP) in C++ we have _unsigned_ integer types, which can represent about twice as big a number as their regular signed counterparts can.

Comment: @nada `long long` can handle the product of 19 digits ( 9^19 < 2^63 ), `unsigned long long` can handle it up to 20 digits (9^21 > 2^64)

Comment: `long long` _must_ at least be 64 bits, but does not have to be _exactly_ 64 bits. I also meant it more generally as a side note for the asker/askeress.

Comment: Yep changed it to long long after @mcabreb 's comment. I'll keep the above in mind! Thanks